# creating multiple recycleviewer programmatically Android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-studio

I wanted to create `RecyclerView` that I can use many times by looping through my `Json` results.
what I wanted was to create categories of products(*`RecyclerView`s*), each containg its products that can be scrolled horizontally like on these  [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/85Oj6.png).

so I searched around `Internet` I couldn`t find anything.

Then I decided to do it these way:

1. create many recyclerView`s (eg. recycler_1, recycler_2)
2. then loop through my Json while adding adapters(`data`) into those recycler

**Now my problem is that I want to add more categories(with their products) when the user reach the bottom, and I don't know how to add more recyclerViews programmatically or any other alternative.**

---

**Here is some of my code:**

**Here is my Json results**

---

```
{
   "products":[
      {
         "category":[
            {
               "category_name":"Audio & TV"
            },
            {
               "inner_products":[
                  {
                     "id":"3442",
                     "product_thumb":"19279c812c9e56a0ca8fea095f36cb22.jpeg",
                     "brand_name":"Others",
                     "product_name":"4ga wiring kit",
                     "saved_amount":"0",
                     "product_price":"269",
                     "supplier_logo":"467909bb980b06aca7588be54fa4cb68.jpeg"
                  },
                  {
                     "id":"3444",
                     "product_thumb":"dd07c851cfaf1830f6b44f7c55298a18.jpeg",
                     "brand_name":"Kenwood",
                     "product_name":"car radio double din ",
                     "saved_amount":"400",
                     "product_price":"2299",
                     "supplier_logo":"467909bb980b06aca7588be54fa4cb68.jpeg"
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "category":[
            {
               "category_name":"building tools"
            },
            {
               "inner_products":[
                  {
                     "id":"124",
                     "product_thumb":"c482e6b5ea0ee76c4e6524b86442bf27.png",
                     "brand_name":"Others",
                     "product_name":"drill bosch blue cordless 18v 4a",
                     "saved_amount":"0",
                     "product_price":"3695",
                     "supplier_logo":"21fa5955772bea6a5a1beae155860e6f.jpeg"
                  },
                  {
                     "id":"123",
                     "product_thumb":"124591fc38e03702774c99fa00515ca7.png",
                     "brand_name":"Others",
                     "product_name":"grinder bosch blue angle 125mm 850w",
                     "saved_amount":"0",
                     "product_price":"799.95",
                     "supplier_logo":"21fa5955772bea6a5a1beae155860e6f.jpeg"
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

---

**And here is how I Loop through the `Json`**

```
final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
progressDialog.setMessage("Loading ");
progressDialog.show();

StringRequest productsStringrequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, products_url,

        new Response.Listener<String>(){

            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {

                progressDialog.dismiss();
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);

                    JSONArray productsArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("products");


                    for (int i = 0; i < productsArray.length(); i++){

                        int[] procustRecycler = new int[]{R.id.procustRecycler_0, R.id.procustRecycler_1, R.id.procustRecycler_2, R.id.procustRecycler_3, R.id.procustRecycler_4, R.id.procustRecycler_5, R.id.procustRecycler_6, R.id.procustRecycler_7, R.id.procustRecycler_8,  R.id.procustRecycler_9};
                        int[] pr_header = new int[]{R.id.product_header_0, R.id.product_header_1, R.id.product_header_2, R.id.product_header_3, R.id.product_header_4, R.id.product_header_5, R.id.product_header_6, R.id.product_header_7, R.id.product_header_8, R.id.product_header_9 };


                        JSONObject categoryObject = productsArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        JSONArray categoryArray = categoryObject.getJSONArray("category");


                        for (int b = 0; b < categoryArray.length(); b++){

                            JSONObject singleCategoryObject = categoryArray.getJSONObject(0);

                            RecyclerView allProductsRecycler = (RecyclerView) findViewById(procustRecycler[i]);

                            allProductsRecycler.setHasFixedSize(true);
                            allProductsRecycler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(Products.this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
                            List<ProductsItems> products_list = new ArrayList<>();

                            if(b == 0) {
                                TextView product_header = (TextView) findViewById(pr_header[i]);
                                product_header.setText(singleCategoryObject.getString("category_name"));

                                continue;
                            }

                            JSONObject productsCategoryObject  = categoryArray.getJSONObject(b);
                            JSONArray singleProductsArray = productsCategoryObject.getJSONArray("inner_products");


                            for (int c=0; c< singleProductsArray.length(); c++){

                                JSONObject object = singleProductsArray.getJSONObject(c);

                                ProductsItems items = new ProductsItems(
                                        object.getInt("id"),
                                        object.getString("product_name"),
                                        object.getString("product_thumb"),
                                        object.getString("supplier_logo"),
                                        object.getString("brand_name"),
                                        object.getString("product_price"),
                                        object.getString("saved_amount")
                                );
                                products_list.add(items);
                            }

                            RecyclerView.Adapter allProductsAdapter = new ProductsAdapter(products_list, getApplicationContext());
                            allProductsRecycler.setAdapter(allProductsAdapter);

                        }
                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {

                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                    Toast.makeText(Products.this, "Catche error: "+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        },

        new Response.ErrorListener(){

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                progressDialog.dismiss();

                if (error instanceof TimeoutError ) {
                    Toast.makeText(Products.this, "Network time out", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else if (error instanceof AuthFailureError) {
                    Toast.makeText(Products.this, "Login fail", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else if (error instanceof ServerError) {
                    Toast.makeText(Products.this, "Server error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else if (error instanceof NetworkError) {
                    Toast.makeText(Products.this, "Network error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else if (error instanceof ParseError) {
                    Toast.makeText(Products.this, "Unknown", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        }
);

SingleTon.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).addToRequestQue(productsStringrequest);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This library is best for your requirement.

[SectionRecyclerView](https://github.com/luizgrp/SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter)